# MS Access 2013: How to display a webpage in a report

Tags: report, html, ms-access-2013

How can I display a webpage in an MS Access 2013 report?

EDIT

Actually I have to make a report showing the snapshot of a different webpage for each recordset. The snapshot shall show the current state of the webpage.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have removed the thanks and signature from your post.  It is not required.  Have you googled it ?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I googled a lot, but did not find anything useful. My question was changed - why?
I do not want to know, how to display a report as a webpage, but how to display a webpage on a report!

Comment: Sorry, It was not clear what you wanted, so I phrased it to what I thought you were after.  If this is not what you intended, then please edit it and correct it.

Comment: As I said, it is not clear what you are after.  Do you want to display a url link in your report ?  Or do you want a snapshot of a webpage ?

Comment: Thank you - yes, that is exactly what I want: A snapshot of a webpage in the report. :) Actually I have to make a report showing the snapshot of a different webpage for each recordset.

Comment: I have copied the comments to your post.  Next time you should do it yourself so that the question gets better.  Next question - a static image, or does it have to be the current image when the report is viewed ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need additional software or code to create Web pages from data in your Access database. Microsoft Access can create HTML files from its data as one of several export options that allow you to also export spreadsheets, plain text and alternate database files.

1. Open your file in Access. Click the Navigation Pane on the left side of the window to open a list of the database components.
2. Click the arrow next to "All Access Objects" to open a drop-down menu. Click the type of Access object that you want to convert; for example, select "Tables" to make a Web page from table data.
3. Right-click the component that you want to convert to a Web page.
4. Click "Export."
5. Click "HTML Document" to open the "Export - HTML Document" dialog box.
6. Click "Browse" and then navigate to a location to save the Web page.
7. Click "OK" to create the Web page.

Source http://smallbusiness.chron.com/create-display-access-database-data-49070.html

Comment: Thank you. My question seems to be changed by an admin: I do not want to know, how to display a report as a webpage, but how to display a webpage on a report!
Please change my question back to 'MS Access 2013: How to display a webpage on a report' - thx!

Answer (score 1):

I am not one step further, yet.

Is anyone interested in writing a javascript for that task:
Create an image of a stated HTML element in the webpage mentioned.

This way I could first generate an image of the webpage and then display the image in the Access report...

Kind regards,
Gerald